# How do I force Windows 8.1 to use files from a "System image Backup"?

Tags: windows-8.1, restore, system-restore

I can not find a way to force Windows 8.1 to use my "System image Backup".

- the "System image Backup" was created via "win8.1 settings", "Search", "File History" which opens the "File History" window (sic) ... in the lower left hand corner of that window, click "System image Backup" which is the link below "Recovery".
- the backup image was successfully created ... however, there seems to be no way to actually use it.

Clicking "Recovery" opens a "Recovery" window (sic) but the choice "Open System Restore" only wants me to select a "restore point"!

Please help me force win8.1 to use my "System image backup".

Answer (score 2):

System image backups can't be restored from within Windows as they're overwriting the Windows system entirely. To restore a system image backup, you’ll need to boot from [Windows 8.1 installation media](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), [recovery drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive), or [system repair disc](http://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/).

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/167984/how-to-create-and-restore-system-image-backups-on-windows-8.1/)